# animate element dynamically on creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to dynamically create divs, append them to the body and set a jQuery animation.

This is where the elements are created:

```
function drawSpot()
{
 var myH1 = document.createElement("div");
 myH1.style.position = "absolute";
 myH1.style.top = GetRandom(0,100)+"%";
 myH1.style.left = GetRandom(0,100)+"%";
 myH1.style.width="40px";
 myH1.style.height="40px";
 $("body").append(myH1);

}
```

And from the time on they are appended to the body, I want to start the animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already using jQuery, you should do it all the way:

```
$('<div>', {
    css: {
        position:   'absolute',
        top:        GetRandom(0,100)+'%',
        left:       GetRandom(0,100)+'%',
        width:      '40px',
        height:     '40px'
    }
}).appendTo( document.body ).animate({
    left:  '100%'  // for instance
}, 2000);
```

By using `.appendTo()` you still have a reference to your original object and be able to chain methods on it.

Ref.: [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/dkuVu/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for creation of elements, and animate it when appending:

```
function drawSpot() {
 var myH1 = $("<div>").css({ position: "absolute",
                             top:      GetRandom(0,100)+"%",
                             left:     GetRandom(0,100)+"%",
                             width:    40,
                             height:   40 });
 $("body").append(myH1.animate(...));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nagCf/

Answer (score 1):

That should work

```
function drawSpot()
{
   var myH1 = '<div id="newDiv">Some Text</div>';
   $("body").append(myH1);

   $("#newDiv").css({'position' : 'absolute',
                     'top' : GetRandom(0,100)+"%",
                     'left' :GetRandom(0,100)+"%",
                     'width':'40px',
                     'height':'40px' 
                   });

   $("#newDiv").hide().fadeIn(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use : `$(myH1).animate({left:'*randomvalue*', top:'*randomvalue*'},1000);` after the `append`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wumrr/2/